# Article name in contact us email joomla

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5

I am looking for solution to a tricky requirement by my client. The scenario is:

1. Site contains courses and all the courses are added as Articles.
2. Each course have a (As i told already course = article) "Inquire about this course" button and while clicking on that button it will take the user into a contact form.

I want to know that how can i display that particular course name on that form and and also i want its name to be send in the email after user hitting the submit button. Does any contact form component providing the feature.?

Please help me to sort this out. I am using Joomla 1.5

Thanks and regards

Jithesh KT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll likely have to write or obtain a plugin to accomplish this.  I found [Mail This Page](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/content-sharing/articles-sharing/7717) at the [JED](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/content-sharing/articles-sharing).  Don't know if it will do what you want exactly, but it sounds close enough that you could modify it to suite your needs.